# CreateFile winapi failed on volume C

Tags: winapi

This is from some old code that worked well for several years, but in our new project it got error. I have replaced all function arguments to constants, and tried using both wide-char and ASCII version and all got same result:

```
// compile with UNICODE=1
HANDLE handle = CreateFile( L"\\\\.\\C", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
// or
HANDLE handle = CreateFileW( L"\\\\.\\C", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
// or
HANDLE handle = CreateFileA( "\\\\.\\C", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
```

The returned handle is `0xffffffff` that is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and `GetLastError()` return 2 which means no file found.

Running program with administrator privilege got same result.

Comment: You need a colon (`:`) after the driver letter: `L"\\\\.\\C:"`

Comment: @AdrianMole It is actually caused by other parts of the program that generates the path name incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: @jiandingzhe Thanks for sharing this. After solving the problem, you can post the answer and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) yourself.